# How to create columns + sequences for GenerationType.AUTO id fields in EclipseLink + PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, persistence, eclipselink

I'm using EclipseLink 2.5.2. I have this abstract entity containing a generated id:

```
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Id
private Long id;
```

I want my application to create or extend my (PostgreSQL 9.3.7) database, so I'm using these properties in my `persistence.xml`:

```
<properties>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables"/>
  <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="both"/>
</properties>
```

After running the application, the tables are created, but I'm unable to insert data using plain SQL without explicitly setting a id in my insert query. So, the generated value strategy is not reflected in the database model.

It is created like this:

```
id bigint NOT NULL
```

but I expected it to be something like:

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('some_generated_sequence'::regclass)
```

When I connect to a Derby database the auto generated id **does** work (a sequence is generated).

How can I configure EclipseLink to properly generate database columns and sequences for `GenerationType.AUTO` id fields using a PostgreSQL database?

I also tried to define a sequence and use it on my id field:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SequenceGenerator(name="global_sequence", sequenceName="global_sequence", allocationSize=1, initialValue=1)
public abstract class AbstractEntity implements Serializable
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "global_sequence")
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private Long id;

  ...
}
```

When I run my application I get this error:

> Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "global_sequence" does not exist

Comment: What do you mean by "default sequence"? I already have `create-or-extend-tables` in my `persistence.xml`, isn't that basically the same as `create-tables`?

Comment: by default sequence i meant, you do not need to create your own sequence generator... my bad, they are not same, but have nothing to do with your problem... how are you inserting a new row... are you creating a new Entity object and then persisting it or you are using plain sql insert statement to insert a new row... ? i guess ID auto generation works only when you are using JPQL or persisting a new entity object

Comment: I was using plain SQL. I'll clarify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generationtype.auto allows the provider to pick the sequence type used, and in this case, EclipseLink is likely choosing to use a sequence table which allows preallocation.  If you want a particular type of sequence generation to be used, you should specify one that your database supports, but beware of the trade off as identity type sequencing require obtaining values after the insert statement, which can limit the use of performance options such as batch inserts and preallocation.

Comment: When I insert data using `GenerationType.AUTO` and the JPA entity manager it works fine. I indeed have a `sequence` table which it is using. But, I would like to be able to use pgAdmin without needing specify an ID when inserting data.